I would like to translate "He can do what he (wants/feels like)" using "Antojarse"
The problem is that some websites or teaching apps do it differently.
I checked on Spanishdict.com and Duolingo and a couple of others but I saw both of these come up as the translation for the sentence "He can do what he (wants/feels like)."
Which is is the correct one? Or am I missing something?
puede hacer lo que se le antoje
puede hacer lo que se le antoja
Edit: I don't need alternate translations.

The slight difference between:

Puede hacer lo que se le antoje

and

Puede hacer lo que se le antoja

is that (1) conveys the idea of "no matter what it is that he wants/may want." Therefore, his wishes may remain in the present or belong to the future. It carries a sense of potentiality and the speaker may not be aware of what it is that the person will want to do.
Instead, (2) refers more clearly to the person's present, real wishes. It is more true-to-life. The speaker might even know what the person wants to do.

Both are correct. But there are many others possibilities.
The most common usage is:

Puede hacer lo que le dé la gana

And its derivatives:

Puede hacer lo que le venga en gana

"Dar la gana" is not often found in online translations because the word "gana" does not have a direct translation into English.
More examples of use: www.ingles.com

Image source Lecturas.com

maybe I should make it more cliear. I know other translations but I need the use of this word made clear. I am not looking for alternatives. isn't one the translations simple present tense and the other subjunctive? If I was casually making a statement that "he can do whatever he wants" which would be correct.

In addition to respecting OP's request for not suggesting alternatives, one has to be careful with dar la gana.  While antojarse connotes that someone is doing something personally satisfying, dar la gana often means they are doing so with a callous or reckless disregard for the feelings of other people - at least in my region.

Ambas son válidas. La clave es el uso del pronombre relativo que, el cual abre una subordinada. Cuando veas una subordinada, es una señal muy probable de que ambos modos (subjuntivo e indicativo) son (o sean!) válidos.
Si tuviera que opinar, diría que el tratamiento que dan la mayoría de los libros es muy pobre: hablan de indicativo y subjuntivo como dos mundos escindidos pero casi nunca mencionan las zonas en donde pueden solaparse.
Yo lo pensaría más bien así: en realidad, en tu ejemplo, antojar no es el verbo sintáctico (el que hace de verbo es puede), sino que forma parte del objeto de la oración (‘lo que se le antoja/antoje’). Al no ser el verbo sintáctico, poco peso tiene en el sentido de lo que se dice. Eso no significa que se puede elegir libremente una de las ~20 conjugaciones, claramente tiene que concordar el tiempo y la persona. Pero, de todas formas, aunque esté limitado a dos posibilidades (a veces hay algunas más), cualquiera sea la que se elija no va a cambiar fuertemente el significado.
En esta página de los Cuadernos Cervantes se dedica una sección al estudio de los casos en los que puede alternarse entre indicativo y subjuntivo. Básicamente concluyen que usando el indicativo, se asume con certeza total que lo que se menciona se cumple; mientras que con el subjuntivo se deja abierta la posibilidad. En la práctica, poca gente va a ser consciente de ello y probablemente alternen entre ambas opciones libremente.
